# rust const fn what does it exactly mean

Tags: rust, constants

### Rust const fn

In the following [article](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-next/const-fn.html) I saw the following:

> A const fn allows you to execute code in a "const context." For
> example:

```
const fn five() -> i32 {
    5
}

const FIVE: i32 = five();
```

What does const fn exactly do in rust? Does it just say that the function can be completely be calculated at compile time (my guess based on reading the article)

Comment: That's necessary, but not quite sufficient. See https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0911-const-fn.html and https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/iksmgk/psa_what_is_const_fn/ for more.

Answer (score 1):

###### To understand const fn you first need to understand const expressions.

**Some** expressions, called constant expressions, can be evaluated at compile time. In `const` contexts, these are the only allowed expressions, and are always evaluated at compile time. In other places, such as `let` statements, constant expressions *may be, but are not guaranteed to be,* evaluated at compile time.

The obvious question is, which expressions are guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time. They are:

- Array type length [1](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/array.html), array repeat length  [2](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/array-expr.html)
- Initialiser of constants [3](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/constant-items.html), statics [4](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/static-items.html), enum discriminants [5](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/enumerations.html#discriminants)
- Const generic arguments [6](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/generics.html#const-generics)

###### So now, what is a const fn:

A `const fn` is a function that one is permitted to call from a `const` context. When called from a `const` context, the function is interpreted by the compiler *at compile time*. The interpretation happens in the environment of the compilation target and not the host. So `usize` is 32 bits if you are compiling against a 32 bit system, irrelevant of whether you are building on a 64 bit or a 32 bit system.

Const functions have various restrictions to make sure that they can be evaluated at compile-time. It is, for example, not possible to write a random number generator as a `const` function. Calling a `const` function at compile-time will always yield the same result as calling it at runtime, even when called multiple times.

For more details, see [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/const_eval.html#const-context).